# Serverless Template Custom Error Mapping Not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-serverless

i'm facing an issue with `serverless-offline` actually i'm using `Serverless Framework v3.22.0`

And my template custom error mapping are not working and i'm not understanding why here is a the part of it:

```yaml
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: "'application/json'"
    statusCodes:
      200:
        pattern: '' # Default response method
      400:
        pattern: '.*"statusCode":400,.*'
        template: $input.path("$.errorMessage")
      401:
        pattern: '.*"statusCode":401,.*'
        template: $input.path("$.errorMessage")
      403:
        pattern: '.*"statusCode":403,.*'
        template: $input.path("$.errorMessage")
      404:
        pattern: '.*"statusCode":404,.*'
        template: $input.path('$.errorMessage');
      422:
        pattern: '.*"statusCode":422,.*'
        template: $input.path("$.errorMessage")
      500:
        pattern: '.*"statusCode":500,.*'
        template: $input.path('$.errorMessage');
```

According to the documentation : [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html)
I'm using like it says the `$input.path("$.errorMessage")` but it seems he is taking the status code but not returning the object itself and really i don't understand why..

[image: My use case]

And the most weard part is that if i use another httpResponse it doesn't take the statusCode anymore ..

If someone has an idea i'll take it with pleasure !
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to get this solved?